# How do you deploy different git branches of an R shiny app to different destinations in shinyapps.io?

Tags: r, git, shiny, branch, shinyapps

I use git as the version control system for a Shiny app.  I have a `development` branch and a `master` branch.  I generally make changes on the `development` branch and, when I have worked out any bugs, merge those changes into the `master` branch and the deploy to shinyapps.io.  However, I'd like to have a testing version of the app on shinyapps.io that use the current state of the `development` branch.  Is it possible to have it set up so that, when I am on the `master` branch, the app deploys to the production location on shinyapps.io, but when I am on the `development` branch, the app deploys to the testing location on shinyapps.io?

Comment: Do you deploy out of RStudio or github? [Here](https://jarrettmeyer.com/2019/04/25/publishing-to-shinyapps-github-travis-ci) is an article how to deploy directly from github, maybe this can be tweaked for the master and the development branch

Comment: @starja I usually deploy out of RStudio, but I will check out that link to see if deploying from github will solve my issue.  Thanks.